# How to get a part of image in jquery / php?

Tags: php, jquery, image

let's say that i have an image

It's size is

> height : 150px 
>  width : 100px.

I want to get a part of it, let's say the full height, but with width between `30-80px`. so it will be

> height : 150px 
>  width : 100px.

I don't want to scale it. I want to cut a part from it. (thanks for editing, it's called cropping).

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the (somewhat little-known) [clip](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping) css property, although it does require that the element being clipped is position: absolute; (which is a shame):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0 100px 200px 0);
    /* clip: shape(top right bottom left); NB 'rect' is the only available option */
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery cannot modify image elements like that. Your best option would be to position it within a parent element that has `overflow:hidden` to give the impression it is cut. Or you can use the `clip` CSS rule. If you actually wanted to make a new image you could use jQuery to gather coords on the image and patch those back to a server-side script to actually do the heavy-lifting and feed the new image down asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Image editing is beyond the scope of JavaScript. You can display only a certain part of an image, but you can't actually change the image file:

```
<div id="imgwrapper"><img src="blah.jpg" width="100" height="150"></div>

#imgwrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#imgwrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Note that with this solution, the inner image is `absolute`ly positioned but the outer div is `relative`ly positioned, which may suit your page layout better than an absolutely-positioned and `clip`ped image.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to try and use a html canvas.

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_drawimage.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Both allow for rendering parts of a source image, the getImageData() function also allows to read back the image data and manipulate it (for the whole image or parts of it).